# Appium cannot find an element by content-description/accessibilityID

Tags: android, testing, appium

I have been trying to get Appium testing setup with Java to test on Android.  To verify my elements, I have been using AndroidUiAutomator.  In the UI Automator Viewer, I can see that the accessibility Label has been propagated (see attached image).  When I use findElement(By.name|By.AccessibilityId|etc it usually just times out and the Appium server terminal console must be restarted to run the test.  I get similar results using FindByXPath.  I tried waiting using a timeout and a waitdriver to ensure that the elements are loaded, but it was to no avail.  I've tried pretty much everything listed in the code below.

```
        /**
        * Created by appium on 12/6/16.
        */
     import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
    import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
    import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
    import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
    import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import java.util.*;



import java.net.URL;

public class FirstTest {
    AndroidDriver   driver;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();


        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Android Emulator");
        capabilities.setCapability("BROWSER_NAME", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("app", apkloc);


        capabilities.setCapability("VERSION", "5.0.0");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");

        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        // Thread.sleep(100);
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        System.out.println("driver1=" + driver);


    }




    @Test
    public void login() throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        MobileElement mo = (MobileElement) driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().text(\"username\")");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 1000);
        System.out.println("driver4=" + driver);
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//EditText[@text='username']"));
        WebElement  elly = driver.findElementByXPath("//[@id=wutitdo]");
        System.out.println("olly-mint: "+elly);

        WebElement element2 = driver.findElementByName("password");
        //WebElement element3 = driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.webkit.WebView[1]/android.view.View[4]");
        //WebElement element4 = driver.findElementByName("");

        //WebElement element3 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.webkit.WebView[1]/android.view.View[4]")));
        // WebElement exp = (WebElement) (new WebDriverWait(driver, 15)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("Trip")));
        System.out.println("dr" + driver);
        //element.click();
        //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
       // element2.click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        //element3.click();

        //WebElement current = (new WebDriverWait(driver,100)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("username")));
        //current.sendKeys();
       // WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='wrapper']/table[2]/tbody/tr[24]/td[3]/select[1]"));

        //WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='wrapper']/table[2]/tbody/tr[24]/td[3]/select[1]"));


        //Select listbox = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.webkit.WebView[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[0]")));
        //listbox.selectByIndex(0);
        //listbox.selectByIndex(3);
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.webkit.WebView[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[3]")).click();
        //Thread.sleep(2000);

        //element4.click();
        //Thread.sleep(1000);
    }



    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {


        System.out.println("driver3=" + driver);
        driver.quit();


    }

}


[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPegT.png
```

Comment: whats the Appium version you're using ?

Comment: I'm currently using 1.6.2

Comment: Can you post element details from uiauomatorviewer screen?

Answer (score 1):

You are not using `default timeout` so appium server can get time to search an element if locator is correct.  You should use explicit wait to load element properly.

Add timeout in capabilities.

```
capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 50);
```

> Use these explicit wait functions based on element type if element is
>   clickable try wait for clickable and if element is not clickable try
>   with element’s visibility only

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

public void waitForMobileElementVisible(MobileElement element)
    {
           wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));

     }



    public void waitForMobileElementClickable(By by)
    {
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by));
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the find by content description on Android you have to use something like:

```
public WebElement getByContentDescription(String string){
    return driver.findElement(By.ByXPath("//*[@content-desc='"+string+"']");
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it keeps giving me an error and telling me that it expects a method call on ByXPath

Comment: can you post logs from the appium console ? because this works on my 1.5.x , havent tried on 1.6.2 yet

Comment: Information:Using javac 1.8.0_111 to compile java sources
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'appiumTest'
Information:12/8/16, 1:13 PM - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 2s 385ms
/Users/appium/IdeaProjects/appiumTest/src/FirstTest.java
Error:(33, 37) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method ByXPath(java.lang.String)
  location: class org.openqa.selenium.By

That's what I get when I try to run the posted function.  It won't even start.  However, when I do a findByXPath, it gives me this output in the terminal

Comment: [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: find
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding '//*[@content-desc='wutitdo']' using 'XPATH' with the contextId: '' multiple: false

Comment: i'm out of ideas :(  try other locators By.name or similar and see if you can get results. if none of the locators works, then it might be some capability property missing.

Comment: It says that name is not an available selector.  Perhaps this is a silly question, but what capability might I be missing?  This is the first time I've ever used Appium, so my experience is fairly limited

Comment: one thing i noticed on your capabilities that are different from mine:
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "")
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.my.activity.here")

no need for VERSION

Answer (score 0):

```
@AndroidFindBy(accessibility = "Error Message")
private MobileElement ERROR_MESSAGE;
```

I suggest using the Annotations provided by Appium's Java Client for finding an element by Content Description. There are a few benefits of this:

1) Speed -- Finds before you need it to reduce time before clicking

2) Customization -- No need to have parity with iOS because you can use an @iOSXCUITFindBy(id = "Accessibility ID") on top of the other annotation

3) Lazily Finds Elements -- Only finds the element when you need them!